# setUpModule, tearDownModule and imports can be out of order under nose

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, nosetests

I have some Python unittests that I am discovering and running with nose. I've observed some strange sequencing of the setUpModule(), tearDownModule() and imports of test modules.  I have this (example) directory structure:

```
test1.py
test_dir/test2.py
```

Both test1.py and test2.py look like this:

```
import sys
import unittest

def flushwrite(text):
    sys.stdout.write(text + '\n')
    sys.stdout.flush()

flushwrite("import %s" % __name__)

def setUpModule():
    flushwrite("setUp %s" % __name__)

def tearDownModule():
    flushwrite("tearDown %s" % __name__)

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1(self):
        flushwrite("running %s.test1" % __name__)
```

When I run `nosetests -s test1.py test_dir/test2.py`, I see this sequence:

1. import test1
2. import test2
3. setUp test1
4. running test1.test1
5. tearDown test1
6. setUp test2
7. running test2.test1
8. tearDown test2

Which is what I'd expect/desire.  When I run `nosetests -s test1.py test_dir` (using test discovery to find test2.py), I see this sequence:

1. import test1
2. import test2
3. setUp test1
4. running test1.test1
5. setUp test2
6. running test2.test1
7. **tearDown test2**
8. tearDown test1

Note that tearDown for test1 executes AFTER test2's tests.  This means that the system is not in a clean state when test2 runs!  Obviously, this can be a problem in a production environment of thousands of tests discovered from a large directory tree.

What's up? Am I misunderstanding something? Is there a way to ensure that tearDownModule gets run after each test module?

Comment: I might use nosetests's [`--with-isolation`](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/isolate.html). However, it seems to have issues of its own.

Comment: For now, I've moved the to using tearDownSuite() instead of tearDownModule().

Answer (score 3):

Since your `test2.py` file is under the same module as `test1.py`, the `setUpModule` and `tearDownModule` methods from `test1.py` both apply to `test2.py`.

I'd just use `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` and place them inside your Test class. This way you will make sure that the setUp and tearDown are tied to each class separately.